# Strip colum values if startswith a specific string pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe(sample).

```
id  name
1   Mr-Mrs-Jon Snow
2   Mr-Mrs-Jane Smith
3   Mr-Mrs-Darth Vader
```

I'm looking to strip the "Mr-Mrs-" from the dataframe. i.e the output should be:

```
id  name
1   Jon Snow
2   Jane Smith
3   Darth Vader
```

I tried using

`df['name'] = df['name'].str.lstrip("Mr-Mrs-")`

But while doing so, some of the alphabets of names in some rows are also getting stripped out.

I don't want to run a loop and do .loc for every row, is there a better/optimized way to achieve this ?

Comment: `lstrip` removes **chars** actually. I will use regex replace instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't strip, `replace` using a start of string anchor (`^`):

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.replace(r"^Mr-Mrs-", "", regex=True)
```

Or [`removeprefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.removeprefix.html):

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.removeprefix("Mr-Mrs-")
```

Output:

```
id         name
1      Jon Snow
2    Jane Smith
3   Darth Vader
```